# Couldnt get response from json

Tags: android, json, http, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I am trying to get elevation [using this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/#PointElevation)

This is my code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locations", "40.714728,-73.998672"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sensor", "true"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE  " + response.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("RESPONSE " + responseString);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("ClientProtocolException " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("IOException " + e.toString());
}
```

I am getting following error

> > *Invalid Request Missing the path or location parameter*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an HTTP POST request with the data. The API appears to specify an HTTP GET request (with the data in the URL).

A GET request is easier to formulate - you can just use string concatenation to construct the URL you need in the form:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=<lat,lon>&sensor=<bool>
```

Comment: do you know how to do that am new into this HTTP thing

Answer (score 3):

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.0000,100.0000&sensor=false");
```

and remove name value pair from code.

Answer (score 1):

you can get responce bby using simple HTTP GET request..

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&sensor=true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json"
String[] parameter = {"locations", "40.714728,-73.998672", "sensor", "true"};
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
// Prepare a request object
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url+getUrlParameter(parameter));
// Execute the request
HttpResponse response;
response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
// Get hold of the response entity
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();



public String getUrlParameter(String[] parameter){
    for(int i=0 ; i<parameter.length ; i=i+2){
        if(i == 0)
            urlParameter = "?" + parameter[i] + "=" + parameter[i+1];
        else
            urlParameter = urlParameter + "&" + parameter[i] + "=" + parameter[i+1]; 
    }
    return urlParameter;
}
```

This code is from my own jsonlibrary and it should work for you. From here **HttpEntity entity** will be full of data. You must seperate them to use in your code. Also note that this http works must be on try-catch blog for catching exceptions on bad condition.